# Validation is triggered in mouse click but not on enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a code that uses ASP webforms and Javasript Queries extensively. I have utilized the enterkey navigation i.e. move to next text field on pressing enter. I have validations in place. The problem is when I press enter key and reach to save button and try saving through enterkey the validations doesnt showup and it looks like it didnt do anything . But when I use mouse to click on the save button the validations popup as expected

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Enquiry.aspx.cs" Inherits="Enquiry" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/nepali.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Styles/nepali.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script>
        $('body').on('keydown', 'input,textarea,select,a', function (e) {
            var self = $(this), form = self.parents('form:eq(0)'), focusable, next, Previous;
            focusable = form.find('select,input,a,button,textarea').filter(':visible');

            if (e.keyCode == 13) {

                next = focusable.eq(focusable.index(this) + 1);
                next.select();
                if (next.length) {

                    next.focus();
                } else {

                    //form.submit();
                }
                return false;
            }
            else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 9) {    //Shift +Tab

                Previous = focusable.eq(focusable.index(this) - 1);
                Previous.select();
                if (Previous.length) {
                    Previous.focus();
                } else {
                    //form.submit();
                }
            }

        });
       
    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript">

        function showMessage(No) {

            alert("Enquiry No " + No + " Created successfully!");
            window.location.href = "Enquiry.aspx";
        }

        function showEditMessage() {

            alert("Debit note Edited successfully!");
            window.location.href = "DebitNote.aspx";
        }
        function showErrorMessage(ex) {
            alert(ex);
        }

        function DateMsg(StartDate, EndDate, Code) {
            var Code = Code;
            var date = (document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDate').value);

            if (Code == "1") {
                alert("Select Date Between" + " " + StartDate + " " + "&" + " " + EndDate);
                document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDate').focus();
            }
            else {
                var dd = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDate').value;
                var d1 = new Date('<%= Session["StartDate"] %>');
                var d2 = new Date('<%= Session["EndDate"] %>');
                var d3 = new Date(dd);

                if (d1 <= d3 && d2 >= d3) {

                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDate').focus();
                }
            }
        }
        function MitiMsg(StartDate, EndDate, Code) {
            if (Code == "2") {
                alert("Select Miti Between" + " " + StartDate + " " + "&" + " " + EndDate);
                document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtNepaliDate').focus();
            }
            else {
                var dd = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDate').value;
                var d1 = new Date('<%= Session["StartDate"] %>');
                var d2 = new Date('<%= Session["EndDate"] %>');
                var d3 = new Date(dd);

                if (d1 <= d3 && d2 >= d3) {

                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtNepaliDate').focus();
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function InvoiceNo() {
            var UserID = '<%= Session["UserID"] %>';
            var PageName = "Enquiry";
            var ColumnName = "ENNO";
            var TableName = "tbl_Enquiry";

            var strcs = "NumberingChequeEntry.aspx?ID=" + "&UserID=" + UserID + "&PageName=" + PageName + "&ColumnName=" + ColumnName + "&TableName=" + TableName + "&Proc=" + "DelDbAccountGroupINfo" + "&window=small";
            var newWindow = window.open(strcs, "Ledger", "top=100,left=300,width=650,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
            newWindow.focus();
        }

        function NumberSystem(No, Type) {

            document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtNumberSystem').value = No;
            document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtNumberSystem').disbaled = true;
            document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtNepaliDate').focus();
            document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtNepaliDate').select();
        }
    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        function BtnSave(event) {
            document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtNumberSystem').disabled = false
            var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
            if (x == 13) {
                var txtName = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1");
                txtName.click();
            }
        }
     
    </script>
    <script>
        function addrowAndCheckNumeric(event) {
            addrow(event);
            isNumeric(event);
        }
    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        function addrow(event) {
            var x = event.which || event.keyCode;

            if (x == 13) {
                var txtName = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Gridview1_ButtonAdd");
                txtName.click();
            }
        }
     
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CashBankBilling() {
            var PageName = "Enquiry";
            var strcs = "CashBankBilling.aspx?ID=" + "&PageName=" + PageName + "&window=small";
            var newWindow = window.open(strcs, "Ledger", "top=0,left=100,width=1130,height=600,toolbar=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
            newWindow.focus();
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="PerfectScripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var specialKeys = new Array();
        specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
        $(function () {
            $(".numeric").bind("keypress", function (e) {
                var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
                var ret = ((keyCode >= 90 && keyCode <= 90) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
                $(".error").css("display", ret ? "none" : "inline");
                return ret;
            });
            $(".numeric").bind("paste", function (e) {
                return false;
            });
            $(".numeric").bind("drop", function (e) {
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function isNumeric(evt) {
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
                // Allow only numeric input
                evt.preventDefault ? evt.preventDefault() : (evt.returnValue = false);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updPanel1">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" Height="550px" Width="1795px">
                <div class="dashboard-main-stock">
                    <div class="dash-sec">
                        <div class="Last-activity">
                            <div class="dashboardlbl">
                                New Enquiry
                                <asp:Button ID="btnprint" OnClientClick="CashBankBilling();" Text="Print" runat="server"
                                    Style="float: right" CausesValidation="false" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="main-left">
                                <table class="main-table-stock">
                                    <tr class="row">
                                        <%--      <td>
                                            <p class="label">
                                                EN No</p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumberSystem" runat="server" onFocus="InvoiceNo ();" class="numeric"
                                                    required></asp:TextBox>
                                            </p>
                                        </td>--%>
                                        <td>
                                            <p class="label">
                                                Nepali Date</p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNepaliDate" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" onFocus="showCalendarBox('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtNepaliDate')"
                                                    required AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtNepaliDatea_TextChanged" onblur="MitiMsg(this.value);"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p class="label">
                                                Date</p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtDate_TextChanged1"
                                                    required onblur="DateMsg(this.value);"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDate"
                                                    Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Format (mm/dd/yyyy)" ValidationExpression="^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$">
                                                </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                            </p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <div style="margin-left: 100px; overflow: auto; max-height: 131px" class="showgrid">
                                    <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                        OnRowDataBound="gvDetails_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="Gridview1_RowDeleting"
                                        FooterStyle-CssClass="footrow" CssClass="gridrow grdCamera">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="SN" HeaderStyle-Height="20px" ItemStyle-Width="22px" />
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Party Name" HeaderStyle-Width="300px">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLedger" runat="server" Width="294px" onkeydown="return LedgerDetail(this);"
                                                        required onFocus="return GetLedgerPopup(this);"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Party Type" HeaderStyle-Width="110px">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="txtPartyType" runat="server" Width="110px" CssClass="gridtextbox groupOfTexbox"
                                                        onchange="multiplication()">
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Customer" Value="Customer"></asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Business" Value="Business"></asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Supplier" Value="Supplier"></asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Other" Value="Other"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contact No" HeaderStyle-Width="145px">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtContactNo" runat="server" class="gridtextbox" Width="140px" required
                                                        onFocus="textboxvalidate();" onkeydown="return isNumeric(event);"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" HeaderStyle-Width="187px">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" class="gridtextbox" Width="183px" onFocus="textboxvalidate();"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location" HeaderStyle-Width="187px">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" runat="server" class="gridtextbox" Width="183px" required
                                                        onFocus="textboxvalidate();"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Source Of Inquiry" HeaderStyle-Width="180px">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="txtSource" runat="server" Width="180px" CssClass="gridtextbox groupOfTexbox"
                                                        onchange="multiplication()">
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Facebook Post/Story" Value="Facebook"></asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Instagram Post/Story" Value="Instagram"></asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Whatsapp" Value="Whatsapp"></asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Direct Call" Value="PhoneCall"></asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Ads Campaign" Value="AdsCampaign"></asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Other Specify in Remarks" Value="AdsCampaign"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remarks" HeaderStyle-Width="280px">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemarks" runat="server" Width="276px" class="gridtextbox groupOfTexbox"
                                                        TextMode="MultiLine">
                                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" HeaderStyle-Width="110px">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="txtStatus" runat="server" Width="110px" CssClass="gridtextbox groupOfTexbox"
                                                        onchange="multiplication()">
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Interested" Value="Interested"></asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Follow Up" Value="FollowUp"></asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Not Interested" Value="NotInterested"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Follow Up Date" HeaderStyle-Width="120px">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFollowup" runat="server" class="gridtextbox" Width="116px" onkeydown="addrow(event);"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" Style="display: none"
                                                        OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" class="savebtn" ValidationGroup="group2" />
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" HeaderStyle-Width="37px" />
                                        </Columns>
                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="voucher" />
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </div>
                                <table class="main-table-stock">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtrowindex" runat="server" Style="display: none" class="Purchase_text"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <tr class="alt-row">
                                        <td colspan="6">
                                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Save" runat="server" class="savebtn" AccessKey="s"
                                                OnClick="btnSave_Click" ValidationGroup="group2" onkeydown="BtnSave(event)" Style="margin-left: 10px;" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Standard practice is to use the TAB key to advance to the next field, that's why controls have a TabStopId. Then the enter key can be used as normal, and on a submit button it would submit the form...